# Is Jackson's @JsonSubTypes still necessary for polymorphic deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am able to serialize and deserialize a class hierarchy where the abstract base class is annotated with

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@class")
```

but no `@JsonSubTypes` listing the subclasses, and the subclasses themselves are relatively unannotated, having only a `@JsonCreator` on the constructor.  The ObjectMapper is vanilla, and I'm not using a mixin.

Jackson documentation on [PolymorphicDeserialization and "type ids"](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization#A2._On_type_ids) suggests (strongly) I need the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation on the abstract base class, or use it on a mixin, or that I need to [register the subtypes with the ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#registerSubtypes(java.lang.Class...)).  And there are plenty of SO questions and/or blog posts that agree.  Yet it works. (*This is Jackson 2.6.0.*)

So ... am I the beneficiary of an as-yet-undocumented feature or am I relying on undocumented behavior (that may change) or is something else going on?  (I'm asking because I really don't want it to be either of the latter two.  But [I gots to know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETN9eNOA6vw).)

EDIT: Adding code - and one comment.  The comment is:  I should have mentioned that all the subclasses I'm deserializing are in the same package and same jar as the base abstract class.

Abstract base class:

```
package so;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@class")
public abstract class PolyBase
{
    public PolyBase() { }

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

A subclass of it:

```
package so;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public final class SubA extends PolyBase
{
    private final int a;

    @JsonCreator
    public SubA(@JsonProperty("a") int a) { this.a = a; }

    public int getA() { return a; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (null == obj) return false;
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        SubA rhs = (SubA) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(this.a, rhs.a).isEquals();
    }
}
```

Subclasses `SubB` and `SubC` are the same except that field `a` is declared `String` (not `int`) in `SubB` and `boolean` (not `int`) in `SubC` (and the method `getA` is modified accordingly).

Test class:

```
package so;    
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestPoly
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public PolyBase pb1, pb2, pb3;

        @JsonCreator
        public TestClass(@JsonProperty("pb1") PolyBase pb1,
                         @JsonProperty("pb2") PolyBase pb2,
                         @JsonProperty("pb3") PolyBase pb3)
        {
            this.pb1 = pb1;
            this.pb2 = pb2;
            this.pb3 = pb3;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (null == obj) return false;
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

            TestClass rhs = (TestClass) obj;
            return new EqualsBuilder().append(pb1, rhs.pb1)
                                      .append(pb2, rhs.pb2)
                                      .append(pb3, rhs.pb3)
                                      .isEquals();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void jackson_should_or_should_not_deserialize_without_JsonSubTypes() {

        // Arrange
        PolyBase pb1 = new SubA(5), pb2 = new SubB("foobar"), pb3 = new SubC(true);
        TestClass sut = new TestClass(pb1, pb2, pb3);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Act
        String actual1 = null;
        TestClass actual2 = null;

        try {
            actual1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(sut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail("didn't serialize", e);
        }

        try {
            actual2 = mapper.readValue(actual1, TestClass.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail("didn't deserialize", e);
        }

        // Assert
        assertThat(actual2).isEqualTo(sut);
    }
}
```

This test passes and if you break at the second `try {` line you can inspect `actual1` and see:

```
{"pb1":{"@class":".SubA","a":5},
 "pb2":{"@class":".SubB","a":"foobar"},
 "pb3":{"@class":".SubC","a":true}}
```

So the three subclasses got properly serialized (each with their class name as id) and then deserialized, and the result compared equal (each subclass has a "value type" `equals()`).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve polymorphism in serialization and deserialization with Jackson. They are defined in **Section 1. Usage** in the [link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) you posted.

Your code

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@class")
```

is an example of the second approach. The first thing to note is that

> All instances of annotated type and its subtypes use these settings
>   (unless overridden by another annotation)

So this config value propagates to all subtypes. Then, we need a type identifier  that will map a Java type to a text value in the JSON string and vice versa. In your example, this is given by [`JsonTypeInfo.Id#MINIMAL_CLASS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#MINIMAL_CLASS)

> Means that Java class name with minimal path is used as the type identifier.

So a minimal class name is generated from the target instance and written to the JSON content when serializing. Or a minimal class name is used to determine the target type for deserializing.

You could have also used [`JsonTypeInfo.Id#NAME`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#NAME) which

> Means that **logical type name** is used as type information; name will
>   then need to be separately resolved to actual concrete type (`Class`).

To provide such a logical type name, you use [`@JsonSubTypes`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html)

> Annotation used with `JsonTypeInfo` to indicate sub types of
>   serializable polymorphic types, and to **associate logical names** used
>   within JSON content (which is more portable than using physical Java
>   class names).

This is just another way to achieve the same result. The documentation you're asking about states

> Type ids that are based on Java class name are fairly
>   straight-forward: it's just class name, possibly some simple prefix
>   removal (for "minimal" variant). But type name is different: one has
>   to have mapping between logical name and actual class.

So the various `JsonTypeInfo.Id` values that deal with class names are straight-forward because they can be auto-generated. For type names, however, you need to give the mapping value explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @JsonSubTypes is needed only if you use the NAME form.  All that documentation I read and I didn't figure that out ...

Comment: The bummer here is that if you use the Name form (which is vastly preferable), you cannot dynamically add class or add classes later.

Comment: Doesn't using JsonTypeInfo on the individual concrete classes makes more sense? Using it over the interface seem to violate the open-close principle i suppose (as in we need to modify our interface on every new addition of a concrete implementation). Please correct me if am missing something here

Comment: @HDave: You can use `ObjectMapper#registerSubtypes`, potentially with something like Reflections.

Comment: As mentioned by c-c, we successfully use `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="message_type")` and then register every class with the newly-created mapper: `mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(SomeClass.class, "some_class"));`.  This works when you know all of the classes at run-time but can't change the base class, so you don't need to list everything in JsonSubTypes.

Comment: An example of what the two previous comments are talking about is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56020646/1371329.