# Custom Jackson Deserialization of a Generic Abstract class

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, type-erasure

I am having issues when trying to deserializing the following class:

```
public class MetricValuesDto {

    private Map<MetricType, MetricValueDto<?>> metricValues;

    public MetricValuesDto() {
    }

    public MetricValuesDto(Map<MetricType, MetricValueDto<?>> metricValues) {
        this.metricValues = metricValues;
    }

    public Map<MetricType, MetricValueDto<?>> getMetricValues() {
        return metricValues;
    }

    public void setMetricValues(Map<MetricType, MetricValueDto<?>> metricValues) {
        this.metricValues = metricValues;
    }
}
```

My generic abstract class:

```
public abstract class MetricValueDto<T> {

    private T value;
    private MetricTrend trend;

    public MetricValueDto(T value, MetricTrend trend) {
        this.value = value;
        this.trend = trend;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MetricTrend getTrend() {
        return trend;
    }

    public void setTrend(MetricTrend trend) {
        this.trend = trend;
    }
}
```

I have two concrete classes which implement `MetricValueDto`:

IntMetricValueDto:

```
public class IntMetricValueDto extends MetricValueDto<Integer> {

    public IntMetricValueDto(Integer value, MetricTrend trend) {
        super(value, trend);
    }
}
```

FloatMetricValueDto:

```
public class FloatMetricValueDto extends MetricValueDto<Float> {

    public FloatMetricValueDto(Float value, MetricTrend trend) {
        super(value, trend);
    }
}
```

Any idea of what's the correct strategy to deserialize MetricValueDto so I can parse it through [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) or an [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)? Whenever I run:

```
restTemplate.exchange("myEndpoint", HttpMethod.GET, entity, DataCollectionEventDto.class);
```

I get

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.resson.dto.MetricValueDto: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

DataCollectionEventDto:

```
public class DataCollectionEventDto {

    private List<MapLayerDto> mapLayers;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private MetricValuesDto metricValues;

    public List<MapLayerDto> getMapLayers() {
        return mapLayers;
    }

    public void setMapLayers(List<MapLayerDto> mapLayers) {
        this.mapLayers = mapLayers;
    }

    public MetricValuesDto getMetricValues() {
        return metricValues;
    }

    public void setMetricValues(MetricValuesDto metricValues) {
        this.metricValues = metricValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

I have basically tried everything on web and I could not make it work; any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: This Question has the Answer to exactly what your trying to accomplish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization Basically you need to define all the possible subtypes of your abstract class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `JsonTypeInfo` works, and adds implementation-specific detail to the response, which later might add confusion to the API client.

I ended up implementing a custom [StdDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html):

```
public class MetricValueDtoDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<MetricValueDto<T>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MetricValueDtoDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MetricValueDtoDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public MetricValueDto<T> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String metricType = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
        mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
        ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> elementsIterator = objectNode.fields();
        Number number = null;
        while (elementsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elementsIterator.next();
            String key = element.getKey();
            if (key.equals("value")) {
                number = parseValue(element, metricType);
            }
            if (key.equals("trend")) {
                MetricTrend metricTrend = parseTrend(element);
                return (produceMetricValueDto(number, metricTrend));
            }
        }
        throw new IOException();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private MetricValueDto<T> produceMetricValueDto(Number number, MetricTrend metricTrend) throws IOException {
        if (number instanceof Integer) {
            return (MetricValueDto<T>) new IntMetricValueDto((Integer) number, metricTrend);
        } else if (number instanceof Float) {
            return (MetricValueDto<T>) new FloatMetricValueDto((Float) number, metricTrend);
        }
        throw new IOException();
    }

    private MetricTrend parseTrend(Entry<String, JsonNode> element)
            throws JsonProcessingException {
        String trend = mapper.treeToValue(element.getValue(), String.class);
        if (trend == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return MetricTrend.valueOf(trend);
        }
    }

    private Number parseValue(Entry<String, JsonNode> element, String metricType)
            throws IOException {
        if (metricType.equals(MetricType.CANOPY_COVERAGE.toValue())
                || metricType.equals(MetricType.PLANT_SIZE.toValue())) {
            return mapper.treeToValue(element.getValue(), Float.class);
        } else if (metricType.equals(MetricType.INSECT_COUNT.toValue())
                || metricType.equals(MetricType.PLANT_COUNT.toValue())) {
            return mapper.treeToValue(element.getValue(), Integer.class);
        }
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

The code ended up to being more complex than `JsonTypeInfo`, but the API client is unaware of implementation-specific details.

Answer (score 12):

Use **JsonSubTypes** annotation with **JsonTypeInfo** to indicate subtypes. The **property** attribute **JsonTypeInfo** is used to differentiate between different subclasses.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "typ")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IntMetricValueDto.class, name = "INT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FloatMetricValueDto.class, name = "FLT")})
public abstract class MetricValueDto<T> {

    private T value;
    private MetricTrend trend;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's the proper way to do it. Keep in mind that I needed to add a dummy constructor `public void IntMetricValueDto(){}` to make it work :)

Comment: Yes, you need a default constructor. Thanks!

Comment: @IndraBasak Thanks a lot for this answer. This was the exact problem I've been stuck to for quite a while.

Comment: @IndraBasak I'm having the same problem and this solution is working for me but In my case, I have more than 50 subtypes. And there a chance to add more in future so there a way we can automate this subtype?

Comment: Where do names INT, FLT comes ?  I mean  how can we know name attribute that should be written for each JsonSubtypes definition