# Jackson Faster XML: how to parse abstract class' children? Mixins?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

We use generated object types from a schema via `xcj`. *Hence, not very flexible control over the types' definitions*. We also use JAXB annotations.

Then, we use Jackson Faster XML for deserialization of those objects. Unfortunately, when we deserialize abstract classes, we get an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of 
com.x.y.z.AnstractType: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, 
have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at 
[Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@2989b3db; 
line: 1, column: 625] (through reference chain: com.x.y.z.TypeA["type-b-prop"]->
com.x.y.z.TypeB["type-c-prop"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->
com.x.y.z.TypeC["abstract-type-prop"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

The above is solved easily for a *single* child of the abstract class by adding a mixin:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(defaultImpl = ChildType.class, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
static class AbstractTypeMixIn {
}
```

and registering it in the object mapper:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(AbstractType.class, AbstractTypeMixIn.class);
...
objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

This works like a charm when a single class is inheriting the abstract one. What about multiple children? Any idea how to implement it for more than one inheritants of the abstract class? If not mixins, what else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Jackson's @JsonSubTypes still necessary for polymorphic deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization)

Comment: The example suggests modifying the original abstract class. This in our case is not feasible due to types being generated (explained above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the mixin only to parse the response, but not to write it. 
So, the solution was to *use the same mixins for the object mappers for **both** serialization and deserialization*. And the following definition was enough:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
static class AbstractTypeMixIn {
}
```

It simply adds `@type` property in JSON for the ambiguous child classes.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonSubTypes` annotation might be useful for you. Refer to [Is Jackson's @JsonSubTypes still necessary for polymorphic deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization) for details

Comment: I tried it, but the example suggests modifying the original abstract class. This in our case is not feasible due to types being generated (explained above).  
Anyway, if this can be used for mixin, it might help, but I would be happy if someone can confirm an example that worked for them.