# JSON deserialize to specific type as Object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to de/serialize **Java** objects. I am sharing the types via a `Domain` package. So both sides know the types.

I annotated the classes with `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")` and I see the `@class` attribute set correctly.

I am deserializing the strings with `Object readValue = om.readValue(record.value(), Object.class);`

I don't know the specific type but all are objects. The problem is that this yields not the type specified in `@class` attribute but `LinkedHashMap` (I think that I generic type `Jackson` uses).

So how to deserialize the strings to the type specified in `@class` attribute as `Object`?

Later I will write logic like `if(object instanceof specificType)...`

**EDIT** using an abstract class/interface to mark all domain

If generic deserialization as "Object" is not possible i could "mark" all objects with `extends MyDomain`. And "MyDomain" is an empty abstract class.

The problem is that this isn't working:

```
Problem on desrialization of record paylod. Payload is: {"OnClientStateMessage":{"@class":"com.domain.message.OnClientStateMessage","userId":"xyz","state":"DISCONNECT"}}. Cause: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.domain.message.MyDomain]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (String)"{"OnClientStateMessage":{"@class":"com.domain.message.OnClientStateMessage","userId":"xyz","state":"DISCONNECT"}}"; line: 1, column: 136]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization

Comment: this is not helpful. i have typeinfo in place, and can't/want declare all subtypes of "Object". Possible classes are all given within domain package.

Comment: Indeed. So you can't just pass Object.class into readValue, you have to pass the relevant annotated base class of all your types.  Otherwise Jackson had no idea that you want to do polymorphic deserialisation.

Comment: i don't want "polymorphic" i want deserialization to the type specified in @class - what ever class that is.

Comment: That is what polymorphic deserialisation is - dynamically deciding what type to target based on a field.

Comment: please see my edit. i created an parent class and lett all others inherit but it isn't working.

Comment: @dermoritz: I'm dealing with pretty much the same problem - Jackson deserializes my classes to the most generic one instead of the specific subtypes. I'm currently writing my own deserializer, make sure to post an update if you figure it out.