# Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype Jackson ION desrialization even after registering subtypes

Tags: java, jackson

I have an interface -

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
interface Base { ... }
```

I have two derived classes - `ClassA` and `ClassB`. I am attempting to serialize and deserialize with Jackson ION to base type as follows -

```
class TestSerDeSer {
    private static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new IonObjectMapper();

    static {
        MAPPER.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(A.class, "A"));
        MAPPER.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(B.class, "B"));
      }

    public byte[] serialize(Base baseType) {
        try {
            return MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(baseType);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public Base deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
        Base base;
        try {
            base = MAPPER.readValue(bytes, Base.class);
            return base;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

I am creating an Object of `Class A` and serializing and desrializing using above functions as

```
Base baseObj = new ClassA(...);
//serialization works fine
byte[] serializedBytes = serialize(baseObj);

//this line throws exception
Base deserializedBase = deserialize(serializedBytes);
```

The exception is -

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class mypackage.path.Base]: missing type id property 'type'
```

I am registering subtypes in ObjectMapper. I also have the annotation for type in base interface. What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Do you a github repo in which we could take a look at?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(baseType)`? What is `cacheValue` there?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Yes you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I don't have it in a repo yet. But the code is pretty much what I have posted here, apart from imports

Answer (score 2):

Your example work with standard JSON with `ObjectMapper` however it fails when serialization format is switched to Ion with `IonObjectMapper`. Tested your example with `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-ion:2.9.7`, fails with the same exception.

There is an open issue [[avro] Support @JsonSubTypes in schema generation and serialization #11](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/issues/11) which implies that not all binary dataformats support subtypes. Open pull request [[Ion] Better support for Ion type annotations. #109](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/pull/109) implies that `@JsonTypeInfo` doesn't work when using Ion yet.

Comment: Thanks @KarolDowbecki Is there any workaround on that for now?

Comment: @nishant not that I'm aware of. I'd ask in the pull request and reference this question. I think you found a bug in the library.

Comment: The open issue seems to be resolved. as mentioned by @GaryPhung. : **It seems the open issue he mentioned has now been resolved. The fix should be available as part of 2.12 of jackson-dataformats-binary**

Comment: @RishabhKumar Where do you see this is resolved in 2.12 of jackson-dataformats-binary? I still see the [Issue #11](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/issues/11) being open.