# Polymorphinc serializing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a base class/interface that is annotated like this

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class, name = "Child1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class, name = "Child2")
})
public interface Parent {
```

This works fine when serializing and deserializing my Child1 and Child2.  However, I want to allow the end user to create his own classes that implement the Parent interface.  Are there annotations that can be used in the child class that will allow the serialziing/deserializing without having to add another @JsonSubType to the Interface?

Answer (score 1):

Well I maybe mistaken here, however reading the documentation, you could just make it work by removing the `@JsonSubTypes`, and have it as such:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization#12-per-class-annotations

```
 @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
 class Animal{ }
```

so any subClass should serialize/deserialize automatically?

> What does that mean?
>
> - All instances of annotated type and its subtypes use these settings    (unless overridden by another annotation)
> - "Type identifier" to use is fully-qualified Java class name (like    "org.codehaus.jackson.sample.Animal")
> - Type identifier is to be included as a (meta-)property, along with    regular data properties; using name "@class" (default name to use
>   depend on type if: for classes it would be "@class")
> - Use default type resolver (no @JsonTypeResolver added); as well as    default type id resolver (no @JsonTypeIdResolver)

Reference: [Is Jackson's @JsonSubTypes still necessary for polymorphic deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665620/is-jacksons-jsonsubtypes-still-necessary-for-polymorphic-deserialization/31666888#31666888)